# How to add an activity "send to messenger" in a picker activity?

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller, facebook-messenger

I would like to add an activity "send to messenger" in my activity controller in order to share a text in messenger.
For now, this is my code, it's just a button "send", it works, but i want it like an activity :

```
func pickerView(sender : UIButton) {
    let message="text"
    let objectsToShare = [message]
    let wsActivity = WhatsAppActivity()
    let content: FBSDKShareLinkContent = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
    content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers")
    let button=FBSDKSendButton()


    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: [wsActivity])
    button.frame.origin.y=activityVC.view.center.y
    button.frame.origin.x=activityVC.view.center.x
    button.shareContent=content
    activityVC.view.addSubview(button)
    self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Messenger" icon will already be there in the activities list when you have it installed in your iPhone. Just tap it and your text will be available there. No need to create your own activity for it.